# Use google chart API url to dynamically set img source

Tags: javascript, image, charts, google-visualization

How can I change the src attribute of an img tag with a google chart api url?

At first, I've this in the html body.

`<img class="image2" />`

Then I want to change the src with a chart URL.

So far I've tried with JQuery

```
$("#image2").attr('src', 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World');
```

Javascript

```
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("image2");
    image.src = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World"
```

However no image is displayed.

Is it possible to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList and not a single element. And your jQuery selector looks for an element with an ID.

Comment: Google Image chart API is deprecated and partially shutdown, if you are looking for a free alternative take a look at https://www.image-charts.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using jquery to select by classname,
use a period instead of pound sign.

```
<img class="image2" />

$(".image2")
```

pound sign is for id selector

```
<img id="image2" />

$("#image2")
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(".image2").attr('src', 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image2" />
```